# How to create an object instance from string class name?

Tags: ember.js

I'm writing a piece of code that converts JSON into Ember.js objects and I'd like to instantiate objects of particular class.

```
var all = json.map(function(item){
   return Ember.run( item.type, 'create', item );
});
```

**How do I fix the above code to convert item.type to the class object before I pass it to Ember.run?**

PS: Ember.js does this in the background somehow, I want to know how.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `item.type` return something like `"App.Person"`, you can use the `Ember.get`

```
var all = json.map(function(item){
   var type = Ember.get(item.type);
   return Ember.run(type, 'create', item );
});
```

I hope it helps.